# Starcraft 2 AI Mods

Tags: starcraft-2, mods, galaxy-editor

Is it possible to create a custom AI in a Starcraft 2 mod?  If so, how?

Comment: I think he means Map not Mod

Comment: There are both maps and mods available in the editor.  You can also make a map which depends on a mod.

Comment: I'd have to review the gaming.se policy, but I believe discussion of illegal mods is restricted here.  If you read the ToS on Starcraft 2 a mod is prohibited.

Comment: Could you post a link to the ToS?  I'd be very surprised if that were the case, because the ability to make mods is built into the Starcraft 2 Map Editor which is distributed by Blizzard with the game.  Maybe the restriction is only for the beta and will be lifted when the game is released?

Comment: Do you mean an the AI for an opponent?  There is a lot of AI in the game, from the unit pathing method all the way up to the AI used by computer opponents.  I wasn't really sure which part of the AI you were focusing on here.

Answer (score 1):

As the new Starcraft editor is very mighty and supports something like procedures and functions you possibly can enhance available AIs with own stuff. For an example create some triggers like "IF player1 has >x units of this and that type, THEN AIPlayer2 order to tech for this tech"

Maybe this style would be a bit too basic, but should be easy to do for non-programmers.

Comment: The Galaxy editor really doesn't have the AI Editor? That was one of the standard features with the Warcraft III map editor 6 years ago. I'm very disappointed and surprised if so.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know for the beta there were several AI mods released, so it might be possible.

Comment: As I understand it, the mods that were released (I know of Starcrack and Green Tea) were both mods that you copy into the data files, overwriting the existing AIs.  I was hoping for a less destructive way to mod the AI.

Answer (score 0):

Starcraft 2 AIs are written in a scripting language called Galaxy Script.
There are a few custom AIs available (some even openSource) at:

[Startcraft 2 AI Forum](http://darkblizz.org/Forum2/land-of-ai/)